Hreflang Tags from the Most Recent Post Appearing in Category Page Headers
I'm encountering an issue on my WordPress site where the hreflang tags from the most recent post are being displayed in the html header of category pages.
This causes the category pages to have incorrect hreflang tags, reflecting the latest post's information instead of the appropriate hreflang tags for the categories.
I'm using the "Juiz Lang Attributes" plugin to insert hreflang tags on post pages.
Is there any code I can add to my functions.php file to prevent these hreflang tags from being inserted in the headers of category pages?
Thank you in advance for your help!

You'll have to ask the plugin developer for Juiz Lang Attributes as it's their code that's injecting them.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
